# Почему одно слово — причастие, а другое — прилагательное

Tags: орфография, морфология, прилагательные, причастия

Газированный — **прилагательное.**
Асфальтированный — **причастие.**
(по «Викисловарю»)

Почему так? Ведь и то и другое слово обозначают постоянный признак-качество (нам неважно, кто асфальтировал и газировал, нам важно, что дорога из асфальта, а напиток с газиками). По-моему, оба этих слова прилагательные, к тому же у Розенталя слова на -ованный/-ёванный названы отглагольными прилагательными. Что думаете по этому поводу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из словаря:

**ГАЗИРОВАТЬ**,  газированный;  **нсв.** что. Насыщать жидкость газом; насыщать напитки углекислотой. ГАЗИРОВАННЫЙ, - Насыщенный углекислотой (обычно о напитках). Г-ая вода.

**АСФАЛЬТИРОВАТЬ**,  асфальтированный;  **св. и нсв.** (св. также заасфальтировать). что. Покрыть ― покрывать асфальтом.

По словарю:  ***газировать*** ― несовершенный вид, ***асфальтировать*** – двувидовой глагол.  Страдательные причастия прошедшего времени образуются от глаголов совершенного вида, то есть ***газированный*** по грамматике не может быть причастием.

А вот ***асфальтированный*** может быть и причастием,  и прилагательным.

Что касается **Розенталя,** то он говорит следующее: 6. Отглагольные прилагательные на -ованн(ый), -ёванн(ый) пишутся с нн: балованный ребёнок, корчёванный участок.  Но из этого не следует, что все такие формы являются  прилагательными.

**А  по семантике?**  Обычно  форма ***асфальтированный*** без зависимых слов  обозначает качественный признак и является **прилагательным**. В этом случае  слово часто образует однородный ряд с другими прилагательными.

Отъезжает асфальтированный, тёмный от дождя двор, где прошла моя жизнь. [Юрий Трифонов. Дом на набережной (1976)]

Один ― короткий, асфальтированный и прямой, но проходит он через село. [Татьяна Сахарова.  (2005)]

Если появляются **зависимые слова**, то  это уже скорее **причастие**, что видно и по однородным рядам. Также в **обособленных** оборотах в большей степени проявляются признаки причастия:

Голливуд ― правильно распланированный, отлично асфальтированный и прекрасно освещенный город, в котором живут триста тысяч человек. [Евгений Петров, Илья Ильф. (1936)]

Еще помню, что окно моей комнаты выходило во двор, асфальтированный, заставленный высокими флигелями... [Б. А. Слуцкий.  (1960-1977)]

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** (в качестве appellatio)

1. Дорогие друзья, я предвидела такую ситуацию, когда **проверяла по словарю Кузнецова** эти слова. Мне тоже казалось, что глагол ***газированный*** может быть **двувидовым**, и разное ударение я тоже видела.

Да, разная информация в словарях ― обычный синкретизм в нашей жизни, вот его и надо минусовать. Синкретизм ― это когда один лингвист думает одно, другой ― второе, а третий ― третье. Поэтому я ориентируюсь **на Грамоту.ру**, пусть уж они следят за порядком,  кто из них главнее.

2. Если глагол "газированный" считать двувидовым, то нет проблем, **так как объяснение будет такое же**, как и для глагола "асфальтированный".

Таким образом, я предлагаю решение **в общем виде** (для обоих вариантов), и теперь наши современные лингвисты могут менять свое мнение хоть каждый день. Мне бы за такое решение **надо бы плюсик поставить**.

3. Кроме того, ответов на вопрос не было почти сутки, никто и не вспоминал ни про словари, ни про совершенный и несовершенный вид.

С искренним уважением к вам, Sharon.

Comment: газировать — газировать несов. и сов. перех. 1. Насыщать жидкость газом газ I 1. 2. Насыщать прохладительные напитки, вино и т.п. углекислотой. Толковый словарь Ефремовой

Comment: ГАЗИРОВАТЬ, рую, руешь; ованный и ГАЗИРОВАТЬ, рую, руешь; ованный; сов. и несов., что. Насытить (ыщать) (жидкость) газом1 (в 1 знач.). Газированная вода (напиток). | сущ. газирование, я, ср., газация, и, ж. и газировка, и, ж. (разг.). Толковый словарь Ожегова и Шведовой

Comment: А газИрованная и газирОванная — разные части речи. Орфоэпический сл. Аванесова

Comment: Мой плюсик и один источник, может, кому пригодится https://pedsovet.su/rus/6805_kak_otlichit_otglagolnoe_prilagatelnoe_ot_prichastia

Comment: Спасибо большое.   Кстати, по вашей ссылке это только прилагательное (там все такие слова прилагательные).  У  Кузнецова (2014) - несов. вид, у Ефимовой (2012) - несов. и сов. вид,  в орфографическом словаре на Грамоте  обозначены и причастие, и прилагательное (2012) , но там могут быть добавления (в электр. виде) .  Вот такая задача http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=газированный

Comment: Там в таблице написано: от глагола совершенного вида — причастие.

Comment: Там указаны суффиксы –ованн- ( -еванн-), которые есть  у прилагательных, но не у причастий. Но если глагол двувидовой, то от него могут образовываться и причастия с этим суффиксом.

Comment: Если суффикс есть у глагола сов. вида, то он будет и у причастия. Нарисовать — нарисованный, заштриховать — заштрихованный.

Comment: Да, всё правильно, но мне непонятна последняя строка в таблице. Там указан отличительный признак - суффиксы ованн /еванн, а в графе "причастия" стоит прочерк.

Comment: Совет. Выкиньте эту таблицу с левого сайта немедленно.  Можно, конечно, спорить в отношении методик объяснения разницы прилагательного и причастия,  но причастия "сушённый" не бывает. В причастии *с**у**шенный* ударение на первом слоге. https://povto.ru/russkie/slovari/orfoepicheskie/avanesov/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988_0569.htm Обсуждать остальное после такого ляпа не хочется от слова "совсем".  Хотя тут есть что пообсудить... Например, безоговорочное отнесении глагола *асфальтировать* к двухвидовым весьма спорно. Но это уже другой уровень.

Comment: Про двувидовые глаголы. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2eJKSaEXL0&feature=youtu.be